# Função do Moq no teste do controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, tdd, moq

Depois de algumas horas tentando, eu cheguei a este código de teste, mas ainda não consegui entender bem a função do Mock, sendo que, sem ele funciona do mesmo jeito.

Obs. A intenção é aprender TDD com [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart)...

---- Controller

```
private List<Compras> _comprasList;


public ComprasController(List<Compras> comprasList)
{
    _comprasList = comprasList;
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetAll()
{
    return _comprasList.ToList();
}
```

--- Test

```
private ComprasController _controller;
private Mock<List<Compras>> _listCompras;

public TestControllerCompras()
{
    _listCompras= new Mock<List<Compras>>();
    _controller = new ComprasController (_listCompras.Object);
}


[Fact]
public void Test_Get()
{
    //Arrang
    var compras = new List<Compras>
    {
        new Compras(){Id = 1, Produto = "produto1"},
        new Compras(){Id = 2, Produto = "produto2"},
        new Compras(){Id = 3, Produto = "produto3"},
        new Compras(){Id = 4, Produto = "produto4"}
    };

    _listCompras.Object.AddRange(compras);
    //Act
    var resul = _controller.GetAll();

    //Assert
    Assert.IsAssignableFrom<ActionResult<List<Compras>>>(resul);

}
```

Comment: Se você escreveu o teste depois do código real não está aprendendo TDD. De que `Mock` está falando?

Comment: A unica coisa que eu criei foi uma classe e um controller só com o Get msm. Estou usando o Moq4. O teste seria antes mesmo da classe e do Controller?

Comment: Não sei bem o que está tentando fazer, mas não parece que precisa *mockar* alguma coisa aí.

Comment: Acho que fiz coisa errada então.... Se quiser fechar a pergunta, sem problemas... Vou tentar entender os testes antes de entrar no Moq.

Answer (score 0):

O framework Moq tem como objetivo simular o banco de dados para que você não precise necessariamente acessar o banco para testar suas regras de negócio. Sendo assim, não faz muito sentido utilizar o Moq nessa lista. O que você pode fazer, é criar um repositório Compras e utilizar a injeção de dependência no Moq, para que você possa injetar a dependência do repositório Compras e simular dados para testar o seu serviço. Ficaria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
[TestClass]
public class ComprasServiceTest()
{
    private ComprasService GetService()
    {
        var service = new ComprasService();
        service.IComprasRepository = new Mock<IComprasRepository>().Objetct();
    }
}


[Fact]
public void Test_Get()
{
    
    var service = GetService();
    
    var comprasList = new List<Compras>()
    {
        new Compras { Id = 1, Produto =  "Produto" },
        new Compras { Id = 2, Produto =  "Produto2"}
    };
    
    //Arrange
    var mockComprasRepo = new Mock<IComprasRepository>();
    mockComprasRepo.Setup(x=> x.ListAll()).Returns(comprasList)

service.IComprasRepository= new Lazy<IComprasRepository>(() => mockComprasRepo .Object);
    
    //Act
    var result = service.SeuMetodoTeste();
    
    // Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);

}
```

Acima é um exemplo bem simples pra você entender um pouco como realizar seu teste e utilizar o Moq, você simula os dados com o Moq para seu método de serviço ser testado e chamar o repositório, isso seria o conceito de camadas. Você testa as regras de negócios da sua aplicação que fica no serviço e chama o repositório.

Um outro adendo é, eu utilizo muito os testes unitários para testar meus serviços as regras de negócios, até da pra você testar seu controller, confesso que nunca testei mas sei que é um pouco trabalhoso, mas ai vai muito do seu propósito de teste.

Pode olhar nesse projeto de teste https://github.com/JessicaNathany/unit-test
pra ter como referência e entender o funcionamento do Moq e os testes unitários, acho que pode ajudar. :)

Answer (score -1):

Não entendi porque retornar a _comprasList com .ToList() se ja é uma lista, e ali não tem nenhum action result também.

Quando você faz Mock de algo, você está dizendo o que aquilo representa sem entrar realmente no objeto, normalmente utilizamos Mocks para evitar entrar em métodos do repository por exemplo, mas isso também funciona com uma service e afins.

Não vejo muito sentido em Mockar essa lista, mas você pode fazer um _comprasList.Setup() e explorar as opções.